# Error in SQL on date caused by value not being inserted

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I am inserting a row into the Issues table with the function below. The table is currently entirely empty.

```
 def insertIssue(self, choice, doc_id):
        date = datetime.today() + timedelta(days=14)
        returndate = str(date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
        issuedate = str(datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
        sql = dbcfg.sql['insertIssues'].replace('{_ttl}','"' + choice[2] + '"').replace('{_date}',issuedate).replace(
            '{_due}', returndate).replace("{_docid}", str(doc_id))
        logger.info("Issues SQL Insert: " + sql)
        try:
            mycursor.execute(sql)
            mycursor.fetchall()

        except Exception as e:
            logger.error("Error in Issues SQL: " + str(e) + traceback.format_exc())
            sys.exit(-1)
```

For the above,the variables are as follows:

```
choice = (3, 3, 'Return of the King', '2', 'Lord, rings, king, return', 'High Fantasy', 'JRR Tolkein', datetime.date(2000, 5, 20))
date = {datetime} 2023-02-08 23:59:50.303823
doc_id = {int} 3
issuedate = {str} '2023-01-25'
returndate = {str} '2023-02-08'
sql = 'INSERT INTO Librarian.Issues(Title, Date_Issued, Date_Due, Doc_id) VALUES("Return of the King",2023-01-25,2023-02-08, 3);'
```

(via debugger)

The error message I get is :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Projects\IntegratedLibrarySystem\app.py", line 276, in insertIssue
    mycursor.execute(sql)
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor_cext.py", line 279, in execute
    result = self._cnx.cmd_query(
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection_cext.py", line 573, in cmd_query
    raise get_mysql_exception(
mysql.connector.errors.DataError: 1292 (22007): Incorrect date value: '1997' for column 'Date_Issued' at row 1
```

The Incorrect date value for 1997 confused me, since the table is currently empty and the value being inserted does not have the 1997 date in it. The query held in the variable sql has the right syntax too.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: The dates should have apostrophe or punctuation mark
`INSERT INTO Librarian.Issues(Title, Date_Issued, Date_Due, Doc_id) VALUES("Return of the King",'2023-01-25','2023-02-08', 3);`

Comment: Note that 2023-01-25 = 1997, indicating you are not quoting your date literal.

Answer (score 1):

From your question I can see that, dates are strings.

```
issuedate = {str} '2023-01-25'
returndate = {str} '2023-02-08'
```

The dates should have single quotes (') or double quotes (") if you are storing those as Varchar (Strings) in Database.

' (Single Quote) OR " (Double Quote) or are used for enclosing string-like values "26-01-2023 00:00:00" or '26-01-2023 00:00:00' in `mysql`
But `single quotes` are more widely accepted by other RDBMS.

```
INSERT INTO Librarian.Issues(Title, Date_Issued, Date_Due, Doc_id) VALUES('Return of the King','2023-01-25','2023-02-08', 3);
```

Comment: apostrophe or punctuation mark is a single quote

Comment: *" (Double Quote) or ' (Single Quote) are used for enclosing string-like values* That is not true in sql. Only single quotes should be used

Comment: Double quotes are supported by MySQL for string values as well, but single quotes are more widely accepted by other RDBMS. As OP has tagged `mysql` I mentioned double quotes too